# "Ping" errors in apache log

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I get a message like this in my apache error log every few minutes:

```
Jun 29 11:13:37 www apache2[22839]: [error] [client 129.130.453.734] ping, referer: https://www.example.org/user/262725/downloadhistory
```

The referer is always a PHP (Drupal) URL, but that may only be because the site is almost all Drupal anyway.  I can't find any documentation for "ping" that doesn't refer to a network ping.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's probably related to the Drupal Ping module.  See [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/ping).